# World image not showing

Tags: 3d-view, image, world

When I try to use an image for the world sky material it doesn't show the image in viewport and render, instead it shows the base color and it's black in render view, it is only happening with new .blends , I tried opening other .blends and it works,

[image: These are my world settings]

as you can see in the picture, the sky is not showing correctly and instead it shows the base color of it which is purple-ish black

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background

Answer (score 5):

Before anything, thanks to Cegaton for sharing a related post about my problem

the solution was to use an environment texture and not an image texture, since the world sky is not a mesh you can deform or uv unwrap it needs a different kind of texture