# how i add a world background with color and with a HDRI sky?

Tags: rendering

i want to have a world bg with a grey or black color for example, but with a hdri sky lighting only, which means i only want to preview the bg color but not the image texture from the hdri, but i want to keep the lighting of that hdri... i dont want to use lamps instead which could be more easier but its not want i want...there is an option called transparent that appears in the film option in render tab, but it gets transparent obviously and it keeps the lighting, but i want to add color to it instead of transparency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109829/possible-way-to-have-a-different-background-than-what-is-displayed-as-the-actual/109836#109836

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here's a node setup in the world material that may solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'm still learning how to use this forum. I think I edited this answer instead of deleting it and writing a new one which I think is the best way to give users feedback of when a new answer is posted. I'll remember that for future edits :)