# How do I export an animation along with the virtual environment?

Tags: rendering, export

[image]

I made an animation in blender, which I want to export. I already know how to export an animation, but the thing is I also have an environment, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I export the animation, this is what the output looks like:

[image]

I have a feeling that the environment in which blender shows it in makes it look better. How do I export it ***with that environment***?

Comment: You want light to illuminate the object a certain way? Put a light that does that. You want something reflected on the surface? Put something that can be reflected. What you are seeing in the Lookdev is because the scene is lit by an HDR image used as environment. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127006/rendering-proper-materials to use an HDR for rendering read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders

Comment: @susu I am reading the answer right now, thanks for the link!