# How to set two different HDRI, one for environment lighting, and another for background, in 2.8 using Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri

I figured out how to use a normal image as the background while using an HDRI for environmental lighting. But I can't figure out how to use a different HDRI as the background.

*Please note I already read this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81011/50766 but this appears to be different for Eevee in 2.8.*

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos . Although I read your linked answers I wasn't sure how to apply them. Now I realize they were on point and need to be applied in the world shader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To render a different background than the one used in the environment

Just enable Film>Alpha>Transparent.

Then on the compositor use Alpha over to mix over the background you want to use.

[image]

Alternatively you can use a background for the world that is only seen by the camera and not by other rays, therefore not contributing to the lights, reflectons,etc.

Set two different Environment background shaders and use the Is Camera Ray from a Light Path node to control the shader mix.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had done exactly this. However the background image remains as a flat (and small) picture despite selecting an .exr, and not like a dome/globe surrounding my models, which is what I'm after. How to get this?

Comment: See edited answer.