# How to Stop World Properties from Affecting Scene

Tags: lighting, world

I'm trying to add a sky in my scene by adding a light blue gradient to the world. The problem is that it lights my scene too bright, as you can see in the picture, the underside of the tree is lit and the shadows destroyed. I was trying to follow a tutorial and the creator said he added some extra nodes to stop the scene from being affected by the world properties. Anyone know which nodes these might be?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134183/how-to-set-two-different-hdri-one-for-environment-lighting-and-another-for-bac?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!