# What's the problem of this situation? HDRI still reflection on metal face after I erased HDRI

Tags: error, hdri, reflection

[image]

During testing related with world HDRI, when I changed the reflection value lower there was reflection of previous HDRI what I erased before which is weird.

Image I uploaded is present world node. I've changed viewport shading, erased previous HDRI file in drive but nothing works!

Comment: My blender version is 2.81a

Comment: By default the viewport will not show the HDR you selected, but a built in one. Enable Scene World in the viewport shading.read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background/81011#81011

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I reopened just ctrl+shift+o. And then problem solved. Thank you for reply anyway!