# Objects look different in rendered preview shading compared to material preview

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Objects look amazing in the material preview mode, but not in the render preview (and also when rendered). I have attached two screen shots of a metal sphere in both viewports. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

[image: gold orb in material preview viewport]

[image: gold orb in render preview viewport]

Comment: Environment lights are not the same. What have you set as world node tree for the rendered?

Comment: material preview is using an HDR image in the world, but that environment is not present in the world in rendered preview. You need to add an HDR image to the world to get similar results. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background/81011#81011.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have put everything inside a box made of plane mesh, and the rendering is superb now. As a beginner i can only improve!

Comment: i added a HDRi everything is fine. thank you!