# Use 2 HDRI at once, one to light the scene and one as background

Tags: rendering, node-editor, hdri, world

I was working on a project and then i got stuck on this problem.

I want to use 2 HDRI at once.
One HDRI to affect the lighting of the scene while other to affect the background.

I am using cycles to render.I know its not photoreal to do that but there are no much shiny parts in the scene so it shouldn't affect all that much.

Is there any way to do this?

Sorry,it says this question is already answered but the answer its suggesting does not help in my case.

Any other Answer??

Comment: Perfect match IMHO. Recommend explain why the linked answer does not help in detail.

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background/81011#81011

Comment: Thanks man. The suggested ones in the second comment really helped in my case.