# How do I light out dark areas

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am learning Blender but I'm not too familiar with lighting.

I am trying to create a simple powerbank and the usb ports just don't get any light because they are extruded inward.

I tried an area light in the usb port but even decreasing it to a single watt just made it look like there was an atomic nuke going on in there, that's how bright it was.

Do you guys have an idea which other light object i should use, or how I should modify the Area Light?

with light

[image]

without light

[image]

---

I used the 3 point lighting technique to light out everything a vit more and added a small area light infront of the usb ports with a small ammount of mW.

Comment: Start with the basics :https://youtu.be/RDbrOpnIY7Q

Comment: The size of your object affects the lights. If you modeled your USB bank in ant size then even a 1 W light might be too strong. Also, the distance light <-> object is important. The size of the light source affects shadows (small=hard/big=soft). In addition to 3-point lights (Emirs Link), an [HDR image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81007/107598) can produce illumination from all sides.