# Tips on achieving realistic vfx?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: sphere composting]

Hi there I'm a newbie (to vfx), below is the image in which I opened a box and with blender I placed a sphere (it's a video actually but I posted image here). But this doesn't look real, what changes can I make to make it appear more realistic?

Also how do I make the sphere part a little soft because compared to photo the sphere looks very sharp.

Comment: Broad questions with many steps asking how to go from beginner to blender master are not well suited for this site. A forum format like blenderartists.org  might be better for what you need. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The first step is matching the lighting. Look at the shadow in the box. It is shorter and has a sharper edge than the one cast by the sphere. So, you would need to move your light source more overhead to shorten the shadow. To make the shadow edge sharper your light source would need to be smaller and or further away. The material of your sphere is up to you. Is it rock, plastic, metal an egg?

Comment: Read this too: [Realistic rendering of mesh together with image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862)

Comment: @cegaton That was a very useful post, so I think lighting and color correction is the key.

Comment: @Dontwalk according to the post shared by cegaton the default material are too perfect for real world so I need PBR and some texture maps to create imperfection.

Comment: So now you are the expert... lmao

Comment: @SurajSirohi you are missing the most important part of the post: **there is no shortcut, not a magic button**. PBR and imperfections or color correction are just one of the many elements. You need to seriously study how the objects in the real world interact. Your CG object should cast shadows, would also create occlusion that would affect the shading on the wood in the box. The box should be slightly reflected on the "egg" (or whatever that sphere is supposed to be). There is no way the egg would be brighter on the bottom or not have a shadow tinted by the fabric on inside the box.

Comment: @cegaton not an egg, it's just a sphere with smooth shade and mix of diffuse n gloss. I know achieving realism isn't a one day work but I wanted to know important topics that are involved in the process.

Comment: @dontwalk soon...