# How to add 3d objects to video? (beginner)

Tags: video, tracking

So what do I need to do in order to get 3d model rendered in video? In my case I shoot drone footage and I want to add some objects in it e.g building that hasn't been constructed yet. So what it takes to do edit like that?

Comment: Hello, your question is probably too broad for Blender Stack Exchange, but you'll find a lot of tutorials on this topic, type "camera tracking blender" in youtube for example

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking